# getting more than 1000 feeds from youtubeAPI?

Tags: youtube-api

I am using YouTUbeAPI to get feed for my Asp.net application. But when i request more than 1000 feeds youTubeAPI generates an error.

**https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?category=Music&start-index=1000&max-results=50**

**Error: You cannot request beyond item 1000.**

can someone help to get more than 1000 feeds using above url?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#over_1000 .  I think this should answer your question.